# How to throw exceptions using fluentassertions in foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I am running a foreach loop for a dictionary and using `ShouldThrow` to throw exceptions on test failure.

But the loop is exiting on the first failure. Is there a way to postpone the actual violations and throw them as a single exception?

Comment: Can you share the code of your `foreach` loop?

Comment: .... simply removing your entire question is not the proper approach. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap multiple calls to FluentAssertions assertion methods in a `using new AssertionScope())`. This will cause it to collect all violations and throw them at the end of the `using` block.